# Is there any relationship between KKT and duality?

Tags: linear-programming, duality, kkt-conditions

I noticed the similarities between KKT and complementary slackness, but I do not fully understand it.

Comment: Complementary Slackness is one of the KKT conditions. Are you looking for a relation between the KKT Theorem (which uses duality) and duality in linear programming?

Answer (score 26):

KKT and duality are indeed closely related. To demonstrate this, I will look at a convex minimization problem in which all functions are convex and smooth. I will make use of [Lagrange duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)). Linear programming duality is just a [special case of Lagrange duality](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/299/145) applied to linear programs.

Consider the following convex minimization problem

\begin{align}
p^* = \min_x & ~f(x)\\
\text{s.t.} & ~g_i(x) \le 0 & \forall i = 1,\dots,m
\end{align}

which we will call the *primal problem*.

The *Lagrangian dual problem* is given by
\begin{equation}
d^* = \max_{\lambda \ge 0} \min_x\left\{ f(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i g(x)\right\}.
\end{equation}

Let $p$ be the value of the primal problem for a given $x$, and let $d$ be the value of the dual problem for a given $\lambda$. By definition, $p \ge p^*$ (due to the minimum), $d \le d^*$ (due to the maximum), and $p \ge d$ (by weak duality).

It follows that if we can find an $x$ and a $\lambda$ such that $p=d$, then it must be that $p=p^*$ and $d=d^*$. That is, we have found the optimal solution! By strong duality, we know that this is possible for convex problems (given some technical conditions).

### Goal: find $x$ and $\lambda$ such that $p = d$.

1. The $x$ that we find should be feasible for the primal problem, or $p$ would be considered to have value $\infty$. So we need *primal feasibility*: $g_i(x) \le 0$ $\forall i = 1,\dots,m$.
2. In the same way, our $\lambda$ should be consistent with our definition of the dual problem. So we need *dual feasibility*: $\lambda \ge 0$.
3. For a given $\lambda$ in the dual problem, the $x$ in the dual problem should actually minimize $f(x) + \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \lambda_i g(x)$. Otherwise, we would be cheating. Due to convexity and smoothness, minimizing this function over $x$ is equivalent to finding a stationary point. So we add *stationarity*: $\nabla f(x) + \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \lambda_i \nabla g_i(x) = 0$.
4. Now that everything is properly defined, we just add the condition $p=d$: $f(x) = f(x) + \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \lambda_i g(x)$, or equivalently $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m \lambda_i g(x) = 0$.

If you meet the above conditions, you are guaranteed to have found an optimal solution (in the case of strong duality).

Note that the above conditions are *almost* the KKT conditions. To arrive at the KKT conditions, we state condition 4. slightly stronger.

4. ALTERNATIVE: By conditions 1. and 2. it follows that $\lambda_i g_i(x) \le 0$. By condition 4. we have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m \lambda_i g(x) = 0$. It follows immediately that all $\lambda_i g_i(x)$ must be equal to 0. We call this *complementary slackness*.

### To summarize

In the convex case, the KKT conditions are neccesary and sufficient conditions for a primal dual pair $(x,\lambda)$ to obtain zero duality gap $p=d$, which implies optimality.

Comment: (+1) so is it correct to say that, under the assumption of strong duality, the complementary slackness condition is logically equivalent to zero duality gap (i.e. $p^* = d^*$)?